# Comparing two fileds in select command

Tags: select, teradata

I am trying to select all records from `Transaction_Table` where `Tr_Amount = Instrument_Number` using following Code

```
Select * from Transaction_Table
where abs(Tr_Amount) = Cast(Instrument_number as INTEGER)
```

However there are some rows in the table where Instrument_Number is Alphanumeric instead of Just Numeric Data. I there a way to skip the alphanumeric instances in Instrument_Number field in the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `TO_NUMBER`, which returns `NULL` for bad data:

```
Select * from Transaction_Table
where abs(Tr_Amount) = TO_NUMBER(Instrument_number)
```

TD15.10 implements a `TRYCAST`:

```
Select * from Transaction_Table
where abs(Tr_Amount) = TRY_CAST(Instrument_number as INTEGER)
```